# MYSQL output multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I feel really stupid on this one...

I have multiple tables users1, users2, users3 with the same structure : Name, address, city, zip.
I need to display all the info in a single table (and later in a csv file).

```
SELECT * From users1, users2, users3
```

doesn't work, it concatenates the info horizontally like :

row 1 > name1 address1 city1 zip1 name2 address2 city2 zip2...

What i want is to have all the rows from users1, followed by all the rows from users2, followed by all the rows from users3. In other words, if each of my table is 20 rows, I want a 60 rows output. 
How can I do that?

Comment: @Santhosh's answer is correct but you should consider combining them into one table.

Comment: I have no use for a single table, the tables are dynamically generated/removed/modified... I just need output sometimes. but thanks for yor comment!

Answer (score 4):

You can do UNION or UNION ALL

```
SELECT * FROM USERS1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM USERS2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM USERS3
```